# DOM element references are not being deleted when the element content is deleted using $(#aDIV).html("")

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, dom

I have a container DIV on a page called "calgrid" that I fill with a calendar-style grid using AJAX. This allows me to update the calendar elements from the database every 60 seconds. The display is perfect and the updating is perfect. Here's my issue.

When I first load the page, I populate the grid locally with a DB call just to get the content on page. At that time, I can access elements within the grid using javascript and do things like highlight boxes with colors etc.

```
function findLocation(id,span,color) {
$("#"+id).css('width',(27*span)+'px');
$("#"+id).css('background-color',color);
}
```

This works fine on initial page load.

However, once the contents of that container DIV is reloaded using jquery "load" ajax call,

```
function setAjaxReload() {
if($('#override').attr('value') == 'yes') return;
$('#messages').css('background-color','#ffff00');
$('#messages').html('Contacting FileMaker');
$('#messages').css('visibility','visible');
$('#hopper').load('ajaxgrids.php','timebits=<?php echo $timebits; ?>&jobfilter=<?php echo $jobfilter; ?>&deptfilter=<?php echo $deptfilter; ?>&profile=<?php echo $profile; ?>&month=<?php echo $month; ?>&day=<?php echo $day; ?>&year=<?php echo $year; ?>',function() {
    $('#messages').css('background-color','#00ff00');
    $('#messages').html('Updating Schedule');
    var blob = $('#hopper').html().split('^');
    $('#details').html(blob[0]);
    $('#wogrid').html(blob[1]);
    $('#calgrid').html(blob[2]);
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#messages').css('visibility','hidden');
    }, 1000);
}
);
}
```

any attempt to access the elements within the container DIV by ID now fails. If I try to turn an element blue for example, the javascript executes but the cell doesn't turn.

Here's the strange part. If I add alarts to that javascript and first ask what is the cells current width and parent ID, the answers it returns are for the state of the original element created during page load, not the element that replaced it during the jquery load.

```
function findLocation(id,span,color) {
alert($("#"+id).css('width'));

$("#"+id).css('width',(27*span)+'px');
$("#"+id).css('background-color',color);

alert($("#"+id).parent().attr('id'));
}
```

It's as if the original content of the container DIV is still there someplace and new content has just been added to it, not replaced it. This is true even if I use $('#calgrid).html("") before the load just to make sure I kill it.

If I comment out the part of the load operation that updates calgrid and still update the other containers on the page, calgrid is completely blank on the page just as you would expect. However, even with no content, javascript can still access the properties of those supposedly removed element as if they are still in the DOM someplace.

I have inspected the DOM and there are no duplicate versions of the container DIV's children. Any idea how I can completely KILL the old elements each time I replace them through AJAX?